# Photoshop: show more precision in 32-bit info window

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop CC 2018, working in 32-bit mode, if I set the Info window to display RGB values using 32-bit (0-1), it only shows three decimal places of precision, which means there are only 1000 possible values displayed.  But a 32-bit file can contain over 4 trillion values, so how can I see more decimal points?  For example, if I draw a gradient with a very small range of gray, then as I drag my cursor over it, watching the info window, I see coarse steps, and it does not accurately display the value of each pixel.

I realize that I could switch it to 16-bit values, so then it will show 32768 values, which is better, but still not enough.

[image]

Comment: Photoshop has coded in hard display limits for decimal points.

Comment: As per Adobe Photoshop CC 2018, there are four decimal places: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZpHd.png

Comment: Even if this comment is not fully related to the question, GIMP 2.10 can display 32 bit color with 6 decimal places through the **pointer** dockable dialog.

Comment: @Helio how did you get that image?  I just added a screenshot to show my display in CC2018 Mac.  Nice to know GIMP can do it, thanks.

Comment: @ElliottB: sorry, I didn't understood that you were using the Info window.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve. The script layer has access to raw values so it is certainly possible to make a dialog to show the actual value if you wished, the even the color display can not show the 32 bit color as it must turn to lower fixed format for display anyway. Note that a gradient will have as manycoarse steps as the pixels it spans regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Photoshop seems to have a hardcoded format for the number of decimal places shown in the Info dialog. You can get an extra digit of precision by using the color picker window.

[image: Color Picker]
[image: Info]